# Is it ok to plug my new HP Laptop FR2CHU8K into a 220V power source?

Tags: compatibility

Is it ok to plug my new HP Laptop FR2CHU8K into a 220V power source (like in the PI, for example).

I know small appliances can be fried from over amperage, but I think most adapters handle the step down from 220V to 110V as they convert from AC to DC, but this 2022 model has "rapid charge" feature, just wonering if that poses a fire hazard or meltdown risk with 220V power source?

Comment: Read the electrical information on the power supply. That's what tells you. We can't guess without that.

Comment: What's the PI. And nearly every laptop I've seen has a SMPS that'll take in a wide range of voltages as per John's answer

Comment: _"I know small appliances can be fried from over amperage"_ - this is incorrect. No device can be fried from overamperage because devices "pull" amperes from the wall, so they receive exactly the amount they want. No more, no less. Overvoltage, yes - volts are "pushed" into the device and any device, small or large, will be fried.

Comment: Yeah, as @JourneymanGeek asks: What do you mean by “PI?” No Raspberry Pi, right?

Comment: PI = philippines and thanks you all for the answers

Answer (score 3):

> Is it ok to plug my new HP Laptop FR2CHU8K into a 220 v power source

Look on the AC Adapter.  Look at the input voltage range. It should say "Input from 90 VAC to 240 VAC" or something very similar.

Almost all modern laptop AC Adapters provide for this wide range of input voltages. Every adapter I have seen in the last decade provide this wide range of input voltages.  **Ensure this is the case for your adapter.**

All you need then is the Adapter to mate your laptop AC Adapter with the socket on the wall.

Good practice:  Unplug the AC adapter from the laptop. Plug the AC adapter into the wall.  Now plug the adapter into your laptop. I do this as sometimes there will be a small spark (adapter adapting the higher voltage) and like this to settle before connecting my laptop. Just a precaution.

Comment: +1 for the relevant part, but please explain the rationale for the last paragraph

Comment: Precaution on my part but I did explain why I do this.

Comment: So the idea here is that if there's a fatal voltage mismatch, you'll fry the adapter but not the laptop, since it hasn't yet been plugged in, correct?

Comment: I don't like surges - that is the precaution. I have not been anywhere where the voltage is so high it would fry the adapter. I just like things to be settled. Probably excess precaution on my part but that is OK with me.

Comment: It is next to impossible to break something by powering its power adapter with an improper voltage. The adapter will suffer, of course, but anything next is generally safe. Getting any voltage at the output requires too much things inside to work properly.

Comment: I am sure you are correct but I just like to be careful